# How to do Web Testing using Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing, web-testing

Can someone point me to videos/blogs/instructions on using Web Testing in Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite and what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182536.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please check below links

VSTS Web Test Step-by-Step Primer: 7-Minute Video 
- http://blogs.msdn.com/ace_team/archive/2009/04/27/vsts-web-test-step-by-step-primer-7-minute-video-by-microsoft-a-c-e-performance-engineer-chris-lundquist-with-copious-notes-and-screen-shots-from-your-humble-correspondent.aspx

Performance Testing Videos Posted to CodePlex
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2007/10/27/performance-testing-videos-posted-to-codeplex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There was a book put out called Pro Visual Studio 2005 Team System that had a pretty good web testing section in it.

Yes, I know it's for the previous version, but not a whole lot changed between the two.